# what will be passed to the response of Java servlets in case a string is passed as text/json?

Tags: java, json, servlets, xss, httpresponse

my question is more security related.
please consider the following code in java:

```
public static void DoGet(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        String input = request.getParameter("input");
        response.setContentType("application/json"); //FP
        response.getWriter().println(input);

    }
```

if input equals a simple string , what will be passed to the client for the code above?
for example I try to pass a javascript script in the code above  will setting application/json to the response type sanitize from XSS?
thanks,
Mary

Comment: No it wont. You would need to check it to avoid XSS. above code would pass whatever you received in input as is to client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the content type doesn't do anything on the server side ... apart from telling the client side to interpret the content a particular way.  It certainly doesn't do any server-side sanitization.  If sanitization is required, it needs to be done before / as the JSON is generated on the server side.

Having said that, with a properly implemented browser and properly implemented web pages, nothing should be "evaluating" the JSON on the client side.  If there was tricky stuff in the `input` parameter in your example, the client-side JSON parser should code with it ... and treat it as invalid JSON.  But, there are potential risks if:

- the values passed in the JSON were used to build dynamic web content; i.e. embedded in HTML, or
- they were used to form HTTP requests back to your server, or another one.

So server-side sanitization is advisable.